# How to get pseudo-random uniformly distributed integers in C good enough for statistical simulation?

Tags: c, random

I'm writing a Monte Carlo simulation and am going to need a lot of random bits for generating integers uniformly distributed over {1,2,...,N} where N<40. The problem with using the C `rand` function is that I'd waste a lot of perfectly good bits using the standard `rand % N` technique. What's a better way for generating the integers?

I don't need cryptographically secure random numbers, but I don't want them to skew my results. Also, I don't consider downloading a batch of bits from random.org a solution.

Comment: unless RAND_MAX is a multiple of 40 (which i doubt) your current approach is already biased.

Comment: @andrewcooke: Yes, although the skew is small when N is so low, I want to avoid that in addition to wasting bits.

Answer (score 2):

`rand % N` does not work; it skews your results unless `RAND_MAX + 1` is a multiple of `N`.

A correct approach is to figure out the largest multiple of `N` that's smaller than `RAND_MAX`, and then generate random numbers until it's less than that value.  Only then should you do the modulo operation.  This gives you a worst-case rejection ratio of 50%.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of wasting bits though; if RAND_MAX == 2^32-1 I'd be calling rand() a hundred million times too often. Caching the results and using it to get floor(RAND_MAX/N) results out of each rand() seems messy and probably unreliable.

Comment: Even a 0% rejection ratio would mean one call to rand() gives one number between 1 and N, which means quite poor performance given that N << RAND_MAX.

Comment: @Andreas: It's ok, I misunderstood what you meant by "calling rand too often".  But in terms of "bit wastage", you need to work in the log-domain; the ratio is more like 1 in 6, not 1 in 100e6...

Comment: @Andreas: You'd only be calling `rand()` ~7.52 times too often.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to oli's answer:

if you're desperately concerned about bits then you can manage a queue of bits by hand, only retrieving as many as are necessary for the next number (ie upper(log2(n))).

but you should make sure that your generator is good enough.  simple linear congruential (sp?)  generators are better in the higher bits than the lower (see comments) so your current modular division approach makes more sense there.

numerical recipes has a really good section on all this and is very easy to read (not sure it mentions saving bits, but as a general ref).

**update** if you're unsure whether it's needed or not, i would not worry about this for now (unless you have better advice from someone who understands your particular context).

Comment: I see, perhaps wasting bits is even a non-issue? I don't know enough about the RNG to say.

Comment: My recollection is that linear congruential RNGs have better distribution in the higher bits than the lower bits. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator: "LCG's do not always use all of the bits in the values they produce. The Java implementation produces 48 bits with each iteration but only returns the 32 most significant bits from these values. This is because the higher-order bits have longer periods than the lower order bits (see below). LCG's that use this technique produce much better values than those that do not."

Answer (score 0):

Represent `rand` in base40 and take the digits as numbers. Drop any incomplete digits, that is, drop the first digit if it doesn't have the full range [0..39] and drop the whole random number if the first digit takes its highest-possible value (e.g. if RAND_MAX is base40 is 21 23 05 06, drop all numbers having the highest base-40 digit 21).