# How to generate a random uniformly distributed number between -32000 and 32000

Tags: c

How can I generate a random uniformly distributed number in the rang of -32000 to 32000. I have already done how to generate random number without uniform distribution. The code for non-uniform distribution is given below:

```
sint16 min= Some value a;
sint16 max= Some value b;
sint32 array[1536];

uint16 i;
for(i=0; i<1536; i++) {
    r= rand()%(max+min+1)+min;
    array[i]=r;
}
```

This code produces non-uniform distribution. I think for uniform distribution I need to remove the modulus operation. Any suggestions please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get pseudo-random uniformly distributed integers in C good enough for statistical simulation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690839/how-to-get-pseudo-random-uniformly-distributed-integers-in-c-good-enough-for-sta)

Answer (score 4):

When the span (max+1-min) is small compared to RAND_MAX, the non-uniformity is small, and people often leave it non-uniform in applications that can tolerate it. (However, they usually distribute the non-uniformities over the entire interval. Your code groups the excess elements at the low end of the interval.)

If you want the distribution to be perfectly uniform, then it is necessary to reject some samples. This trims the number of possible values so that it is a perfect multiple of the desired span:

```
Let span = max+1-min.
Let M = the largest multiple of span not greater than RAND_MAX+1.

// Get samples from random-number generator until one is in range.
do
    sample = rand();
while (M <= sample);

// Scale and translate to desired interval.
sample = sample / (M/span) + min;
```

(This assumes that span ≤ RAND_MAX+1. If you want a bigger span than `rand` provides, you must “paste together” samples from `rand` to make bigger numbers. However, it will still be necessary to use rejection to trim the samples, unless the span is a factor of some power of RAND_MAX+1.)

Comment: The only problem here is that for the numbers given, `span` is equal to 64001, and since `RAND_MAX` might be as low as 32767, there might be no suitable value of M.

Comment: @caf: That was addressed in the answer four minutes before your comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , going through ur resume I can to know you have done some work on FFT. What I have to do is that I have to generate random values as input for fft for the real and imaginary parts. But the distribution of how that values be generated should be uniform. I am trying to do what you have mentioned, but the results are not correct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Right, but the value of `min` and `max` are specified in this question, so it's actually a real issue in this particular case.

Comment: @caf: My comment does not say it is not an issue; my comment says the issue was addressed. Simply combine the results of successive calls of `rand` to make a larger value. Then apply rejection.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , yes I have to do it for the 16 bit values because I have to do it accordingly with the TI dsp processor.

Comment: @IO8aHcyKS1ygst4CCbfI: I am not sure why you are generating random values for an FFT. I do it for two reasons: To generate test data. To demonstrate that the FFT can be used to find a signal in noise. Neither of those needs a perfectly uniform distribution. When you write “the results are not correct”, it does not tell readers in what way the results are not correct or what the correct results should be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rand()`, returns uniformly distributed integral numbers in the range `[0,RAND_MAX]`, you can generate uniformly distributed numbers in the range `[0,N]` easily, as long as `N<=RAND_MAX`.

```
int uniform_rand(int N)
{
    int res;

    do{
        res=rand();
    }while(res>N);

    return res;
}
```

You can also shift the distribution to cover the range `[min,max]` as long as `max-min <= RAND_MAX` and `max>=min` of course.

```
int sample = min + uniform_rand(max-min);
```

**Working example**

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50fa635270697fbf

**Notice**

While this solution is straightforward, you can dramatically increase performance of the `uniform_rand()` function by using:

> the largest multiple of N not greater than RAND_MAX+1.

as pointed out in Eric's answer.

---

*EDIT: Completely revised my initial answer after caf's legitimate criticism. (see comments)*

Comment: thx hexist, i adapted my suggestion and casted the rand() value

Comment: This is no better than the code in the question in terms of generating a uniform distribution.

Comment: @caf In what way? Supposed `rand()` is uniform, the division is uniform as well, and if I do `*2*32000` and `-32000`, it stays uniform over the respective ranges.

Comment: @glglgl: `rand()` can only generate `RAND_MAX + 1` distinct values, so the same is true of this expression (there are `RAND_MAX + 1` different values that it can generate, and a large number of floating point values in between those numbers that it cannot).  When this expression is converted back to an integer (as required in the question), it can have one of 64001 different values.  If `RAND_MAX + 1` is not an even multiple of 64001 (which is extremely unlikely), then some output values must necessarily be mapped from more `rand()` values than others.

Comment: @caf It's been a long time but of course I agree with you. This time it should work.

Answer (score -3):

The modulo operation gives only a slight advantage to lower numbers, so we could non-strictly consider the distribuiton uniform.
With this regard, you could generate random numbers between -32000,32000 like this:

```
r = rand() % 64000;
r -= 32000;
```

Comment: That's exactly what the code in the question does, and as the OP correctly notes, it's *not* a uniform distribution.

Comment: The modulo method may skew the distribution severely, depending on the values involved. E.g., if RAND_MAX is 32767 and the desired span is 13000, then 60% of the results are below the midpoint. (`rand` return values from 0 to 6499, 13000 to 19499, and 26000 to 32767 are mapped to values from 0 to 6499, so 19768 of 32768 values are below the midpoint.)

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is 32767 then this method is even worse, because it'll never return any values greater than 767.

Comment: I did not know the skewing could be this huge. Thanks both for your clarifying comments and sorry for trying to answer a question, having extreme lack of insight in the matter.